# How i can open separate terminal for each thread created in my application?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, terminal

see basically i have one multi-thread application in which i want to see the result & printf and all output of each thread on different terminal so how can i do that.?

**Example** :

if there are two thread created in ma application then i want to open two separate terminal for each thread's output.

```
note: all i want to do in c language with my linux machine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that prints a line on a different tty:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[ 1 ] : "/dev/ttys017";
    FILE *tty = fopen( path, "a" );
    if( tty == NULL ) {
        perror( path );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    fputs( "a string\n", tty );
}
```

Each thread could open a FILE * on a terminal specified on
the command line.  If you want to create the terminals, you
can check the documentation for openpty, etc. To get the
name of a particular terminal, just run "tty" in a shell on 
that terminal.